# Why is there this annoying pink highlight at end of my comment?

Tags: sublimetext3

I can't figure out why there is this pink highlight at the end of this comment. Please help, it's driving me crazy.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it’s trying (incorrectly) to parse your comment and finding an unclosed string literal. What happens if you remove the apostrophe?

Comment: @EdCottrell The problem appears to start earlier, actually.

Comment: Fair enough. I’m not very familiar with JSX and, frankly, find it confusing. Have a +1.

Comment: You need to install an JSX-aware syntax highlighter such as [Babel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel)

Answer (score 2):

Take a close look at the body of the `App` function. Sublime doesn't recognize JSX syntax (i.e, HTML/XML literals in Javascript code) and is getting hopelessly confused -- it is interpreting the body of `App` as a bunch of less-than and greater-than operators, followed by a very long regular expression starting with `/div>` and ending several lines later. This leaves the syntax highlighter completely out of sync for the rest of the file.

You'll need to install a syntax plugin for Sublime which adds support for JSX. [sublime-jsx](https://github.com/ccampbell/sublime-jsx) looks like a candidate.